# How can i parse each String keeps in single variable

Tags: java, android, jsoup

i wanna parse each `<tr>` block's strings seperately variables i mean;
every string values must be like this;
"***Air Wisconsin USA 1965 10.7 high 1980 0 0 Under contract to US Airways***"
My datas keeps Datas String Variable

Here this HTML :

```
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#BAACA3">Air Wisconsin</td>
    <td bgcolor="#BAACA3">USA</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">1965</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">10.7</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">high</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">1980</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">0</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">0</td>
    <td bgcolor="#BAACA3">Under contract to US Airways</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#BAACA3">Aeroflot Russian Airlines</td>
    <td bgcolor="#BAACA3">Russia</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">2000</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">5.8</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">high</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">1996</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">0</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">0</td>
    <td bgcolor="#BAACA3">&nbsp;  </td>
  </tr>
```

Here this html parser;

```
try{
                final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.planecrashinfo.com/accidents.htm").get();
                title = doc.title();
                Elements links = doc.select("td.BAACA3");

                // builder.append(title).append("\n");
                for (Element link : links) {

                    builder.append("\n").append("").append(link.text());
                    Datas= builder.toString();

                }

            }catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solve my problem solution is here;

```
        int i =0;
        try{
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String Blank="";
            String Explanation="";
            String dizi[] = {"AIRLINE : ","COUNTRY : ","BEGAN OPERATION : ","AVERAGE AGE OF FLEET : ","PASSENGER VOLUME :","LAST FATAL ACCIDENT : ",
                    "FATAL ACCIDENTS LAST 10 YRS : ","FATAL ACCIDENTS LAST 20 YRS : ","EXPLANATION : "};

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.planecrashinfo.com/accidents.htm").get();
            title = doc.title();
            Elements links = doc.select("td");

            // builder.append(title).append("\n");
            for (Element link : links) {
                if (i==dizi.length){
                    i=0;
                    Blank=":DENEME:";


                }else{
                    Blank="";

                }
                builder.append("\n").append(Blank+dizi[i]).append(link.text()+Explanation);
                Datas= builder.toString();





                i++;

            }

        }catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and String builder ;

```
 String currentString = Datas;


    String[] separated = currentString.split(":DENEME:");
    for (int i=1; i<separated.length;i++) {


        Person person = new Person(""+(i) + "", separated[i],"");
        persons.add(person);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple function to parse your data. Please check if it works with your requirement.

[Run Online](https://pl.kotl.in/leQAEpD0C)

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern


const val data = """
   <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#BAACA3">Air Wisconsin</td>
    <td bgcolor="#BAACA3">USA</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">1965</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">10.7</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">high</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">1980</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">0</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">0</td>
    <td bgcolor="#BAACA3">Under contract to US Airways</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#BAACA3">Aeroflot Russian Airlines</td>
    <td bgcolor="#BAACA3">Russia</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">2000</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">5.8</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">high</td>

    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">0</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#BAACA3">0</td>
    <td bgcolor="#BAACA3">&nbsp;  </td>
  </tr>
"""

val regExp: Pattern = Pattern.compile(".+>(.+)</td>")

fun main() {

    val lineList = parseData(data)

    for (line in lineList) {
        println(line)
    }
}

private fun parseData(data: String): MutableList<String> {

    val lineList = mutableListOf<String>()
    val trs = data.split("</tr>")
    for (tr in trs) {
        var x = ""
        val lines = tr.split("\n")
        for (line in lines) {
            val matcher = regExp.matcher(line)
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                val y = matcher.group(1)
                if (y.trim() != "&nbsp;") {
                    x += " $y"
                }
            }
        }
        lineList.add(x)
    }
    return lineList
}
```

**Output**

```
 Air Wisconsin USA 1965 10.7 high 1980 0 0 Under contract to US Airways
 Aeroflot Russian Airlines Russia 2000 5.8 high 0 0
```

Although it's in Koltin, it'll be easy to convert to `Java`. 
Please let me know if you need any help on that.